# Can I use a Nuget package written in .NET Core in a regular .NET project?

Tags: .net-core

I would like to write a REST API client in .NET Core, publish it as a Nuget package and use it in a regular .NET project. Is that possible? Do I have to install .NET Core on the server where the project runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use a (regular) .NET version that is compatible with the .NET Standard version of your package, yes it is possible.
You can find the link between .NET Standard version and .NET version [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library)

And you don't have to have .NET Core on the server that runs your regular .NET project.

Comment: Plus a very recent NuGet and you programmed against netstandard which is not the most recent 1.6 but more 1.5 or 1.4. Check what asp.net needs.